# How can I take control of my domain that is registered to me but controlled by web developers?

Tags: dns

I've got a problem where I have a .co.uk domain of which I am the registrant but my web developers control the domain via easyspace.com. I'm not using the web developers anymore and it ended on bad terms so I would like to change my domain to another registrar without getting them involved. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: @amdfan - not strictly speaking, but domains are an important factor in web programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do anything with your domain, you need to be a registered user for it. for every domain, there 4 types of registered user:

- Registrant/Owner
- Administrative Contact
- Billing Contact
- and Technical Contact

If you do a [whois](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp) look-up of your domain name you can see if you are one of those registered users.

If you are, you should be able to contact the Registrar of record (i.e. GoDaddy, Network Solutions, GKG, etc.) and gain an account control login if you do not already have a login for them.

Once you have an account, you can change the Name Servers thereby pointing your site to a different server than it is currently, or initiate a transfer to a new registrar (which costs money - typically the price of a 1 year registration)

Comment: Thanks Rob. I know from the WHOIS that I am the the registrant. The registrant's address has been omitted from WHOIS so I'm not sure what this is. There doesn't appear to be anything set for the admin/billing/technical contact.

I'll try to do what you suggested and contact the registrar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Tell them to give you control of it. You're not *asking* them to do something for you, you're just demanding them to hand over what's yours (assuming the domain is yours).

Answer (score 0):

If you own the domain name, you should be able to change the information with the registrar to point it at another hosting service or your own.

Answer (score -2):

Change your domain host to point to a new name server that you control.

You may lose your web site code but can always start a fresh.

Comment: I think if he knew how to do that he wouldn't be asking! Even I don't know what you're talking about.